# Can the Blazor pages change from public to internal?

Tags: blazor

Its forcing me to declare many of my classes as public rather than internal because attributes like [Parameter] force the property type to become public which forces the data type to be public as well, when internal should have been sufficient for the property type.

Comment: Hi, can you share a [mre]?

Comment: Why do you care if your pages are public and not internal?  You for some reason want to restrict access to page types from projects that depend on your Blazor project?

Comment: @ConnorLow Any empty Blazor page will constitute a reproducible example. There is no way to change its class to internal.

Comment: @KirkWoll I am fine with the Blazor page itself being public, the problem is the viral nature of public. It forces me to make many other types from my project from internal to public, recursively, whenever I want to use them in the code section of the page if they are to be a [Parameter].

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for error BL0004](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/diagnostics/bl0004?view=aspnetcore-7.0) state that "Component parameters are required to be public and must have a public setter", and to fix, we should "make the property and its setter public."

I attempted to follow the instructions on the suggested link about [implementing SetParametersAsync manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0#implement-setparametersasync-manually), although the error message seems to persist.

It is unfortunate because it forces our classes to be public as you mentioned, but Blazor is still relatively new, so this could be the case of a feature that hasn't fully progressed yet; hopefully in the future that is addressed.